# Is there a way to convert a Next.js app to React Native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, tailwind-css

I have been using Next.js with tailwindcss and love this combo. I have already made a web app and want to also make an ios an android version. Is there a way to take my existing Next.js project and convert it to a mobile app or do I have to start from scratch and make a React Native app? Tailwindcss is not as good on React Native as it is on React.js or Next.js, so if this is the case, what's a good alternative to tailwindcss for React Native? I ultimately want to code one thing and have it as a web, ios, and android version. If I want to accomplish this does that mean that I should use exclusively React Native moving forward?

Answer (score 6):

> Is  there a way to take my existing Next.js project and convert it to a mobile app or do I have to start from scratch and make a React Native app?

First of all , there is no direct way to convert nextjs to react-native. You have work on the design (UI part) from begining. You also need to change the way you route through the pages using `react-native navigation`  however you can use the same backend logic here like  react-hooks, etc.

> what's a good alternative to tailwindcss for React Native?

If you only want to use tailwindCSS, then you need to install additional npm package called `twrnc` [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twrnc) where you can use tailwind. Other options include conventional way of styling using StyleSheet or Styled-Components [docs](https://styled-components.com/).